# Opening a txt file automatically using OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

What I am trying to do is to read in a file to a richTextBox automatically with the OnSelectedIndexChange method. There arent any errors, it just flat out doesnt work. Heres the code that I am working with

```
    public void comboBox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedPath = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\" + selectedPath + "\\ " + "Comment" + ".txt"))
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0500);
                System.IO.StreamReader textFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\" + selectedPath + "\\ " + "Comment" + ".txt");
                richTextBox1.Text = textFile.ReadToEnd();
                textFile.Close();
            }
            catch
            {                
                MessageBox.Show("Error: File cannot be opened!", "Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No comment was found in this folder", "Alert");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Make sure the file isn't empty.

Comment: make sure the event handler is actually registered with your `richTextBox`. (this doesn't just work by name...). Also, add a `Debug.WriteLine("blablabla")` at the beginning of your handler, so you know it is being called.

Comment: @felipeoriani He said there isn't any error. It works but doesn't show the file content.

Comment: @DarenThomas You mean registered to the comboBox... The event is index change on a combo box. The RTB only shows results.

Comment: @DarenThomas What do you mean by it being registered with my richTextBox?

Comment: i am disappointed at the fact that nobody noticed the verbatim string with double slashes... @heinst please read my answer below

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal please do not leave bad edits anymore....you mess up answers by doing so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun, lets have you try something. First, replace the following line:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\" + selectedPath + "\\ " + "Comment" + ".txt"))
```

with this:

```
if(File.Exists(string.Format("C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\{0}\\Comment.txt", selectedPath)))
```

It looks like you had an extra space (`"\\ " + "Comment"`), so I'm sure that's why it never hits this block of code. Also, anytime you have an object that needs to be closed/disposed, more often than not it implements IDisposable, meaning you should encapsulate the object within a `using` block:

```
Thread.Sleep(0500);
try
{
    using(System.IO.StreamReader textFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(string.Format("C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\{0}\\Comment.txt", selectedPath)))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = textFile.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
catch
{                
    MessageBox.Show("Error: File cannot be opened!", "Error");
}
```

However, this can be simplified even further by bypassing the StreamReader entirely and using System.IO.File.ReadAllText instead:

```
richTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string.Format("C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\{0}\\Comment.txt", selectedPath));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one problem comes from the fact that you have:

`@"C:\\Mavro\\MavBridge\\" + selectedPath + "\\ " + "Comment" + ".txt"`

Since you are using a verbatim string (the **@** at the beginning), you do not need to put double slashes.

For the rest, make sure your file exists.

Later edit: also I am not sure if you copy/pasted in a rush or something like that, but did you actually put the `catch` block **inside** the `try` ?

Comment: Windows doesn't actually care if you put multiple backslashes. You're correct that it shouldn't be that way, but it won't break anything (right now) to use extra backslashes (unless you start with `@"\\...` in which case it will think you are using a UNC path).

Comment: @alegen The catch and try thing is not like that in my code....i know how to use them

Answer (score 1):

1) What is the error you see?

2) Are you positive the file exists?

3) Are you positive the path created by your code is the path you are expecting?

4) Why are you sleeping the thread?

5) Why not just use [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext)?

6) [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) will return false if the code is running with permissions that do not have access to a file, even if the file does exist. Does the user your code is running as, have permissions?

> true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the
>   name of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns
>   false if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If
>   the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified
>   file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless
>   of the existence of path.

and

> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to
>   determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations
>   that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid
>   characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if
>   the caller does not have permission to read the file.

Comment: I originally had the same exact code with a button and it worked perfectly....friend didnt like it so I am changing it to show onselectedindexchanged

Comment: Thread.Sleep because it would jump to quickly to the catch when it shouldnt have

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of @ before each string. Your directory as it currently is uses actual double slashes instead of C:\Mavro\MavBridge. Use single slashes with \ or go with @ at the beginning, but don't use both.

Also, I would strongly suggest using Path.Combine instead of concatenating pieces together like that.